# Google App Script Advanced Service: Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

https://spreadsheet.dev/automatically-convert-excel-spreadsheets-to-google-sheets-using-apps-script

On the page above, Drive API is introduced to convert excel file to Google Sheet

```
  let blob = excelFile.getBlob();
  let config = {
    title: "[Google Sheets] " + excelFile.getName(),
    parents: [{id: excelFile.getParents().next().getId()}],
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };
  let spreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(config, blob);
```

I've been checking Google Drive API's documentation and references, but couldn't find anything regarding `Drive.Files` and `Drive.Files.insert`. I am seeking the right documentation so I can learn to use these interfaces myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the detailed document of Drive API of Advanced Google services is not been officially published. But, in your situation, I thought that the document at the autocomplete of the script editor of Google Apps Script might be useful.

When the script editor of Google Apps Script is used, you can use the autocomplete of each method. In this case, when Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, this autocomplete can be also used for the methods of Drive API. When this is used, the documents of each method can be seen as follows. As a sample, `Drive.Files.insert` is used.

[image]

This completion includes an explanation of the method. In the case of `Drive.Files.insert`, it is found that it is `Insert a new file.` and the arguments are

- `resource: Drive_v2.Drive.V2.Schema.File`

  - This is a request body of "Files: insert" of Drive API v2 [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert#request-body)
- `mediaData: Blob`

  - This is a Blob.
- `optionalArgs: Object`

  - This is the query parameter of "Files: insert" of Drive API v2 [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert#parameters)

, respectively. From this, it is found that this is Drive API v2. And, `Drive_v2.Drive.V2.Schema.File` is returned. This can be seen at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files).

I thought that this document of the autocomplete with the script editor might be useful for understanding how to use Drive API at Advanced Google services.

#### Note:

- This autocomplete can be also used for all APIs (Sheets API, Docs API, and so on) of Advanced Google services. I think that the document shown with the autocomplete with the script editor might be useful for understanding how to use the APIs at Advanced Google services.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Using autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services#using_autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

You may look into the use of `Drive.Files` and `Drive.Files.insert` under [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

It is somewhat the same use of Drive API, but the provided code on the reference you have provided leans toward using Drive API on App Script (which has a somewhat different syntax as oppose to using Drive API with other languages)

References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/samples

Comment: Ya I've come across these pages. But I still don't get where to see the detail usage of `Drive.Files.insert()`, like how many parameters it takes, and what each parameter is.

Comment: does this url help? I already included this on the answer https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert