# I want use 'contactGroups.delete' by GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I want use 'contactGroups.delete' by GAS
I don't understand why it's an error

`People.ContactGroups.delete({ "resourceName" : "contactGroups/8d49618c890eb1" });`

error

> TypeError: People.ContactGroups.delete is not a function

[reference](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/delete?hl=ja)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the autocomplete of the script editor, it seems that `People.ContactGroups.remove(resourceName: string, optionalArgs: Object)`. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75480727) And, if your `resourceName` is the valid value, how about the following modification?

```js
People.ContactGroups.remove("contactGroups/8d49618c890eb1");
```

- As additional information, if you want to use `deleteContacts`, please use it like `People.ContactGroups.remove("contactGroups/8d49618c890eb1", {deleteContacts: true});`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/delete)

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful answer.
I was able to solve it and learn from it.